# Ubuntu insists on installing git 1.7

Tags: linux, ubuntu, git, package-management

I had Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and I recently upgraded to 12.10.
Though I already have git 1.8 installed, update-manager keeps trying to install `git` and `git-man` version 1.7 (which obviously fails)!

Any idea why that happens? How can I get rid of that update?!

[image: Screenshot:]

Comment: Use a different repository if you want a newer git version: [How can I update to a newer version of Git](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33617/how-can-i-update-to-a-newer-version-of-git-using-apt-get/33618#33618)

Comment: @Marco I used `checkinstall` which, I believe, creates a `.deb` file; and as you can see in the screenshot, it is detected by apt. That's what I'm curious about! It's a clean installation, yet update-manager still offers an earlier version!

Answer (score 1):

If you check on the ubuntu package list, for the 12.10 ubuntu version the [git version](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=git-core) is 1.7.10.4.

I don't know how you install the 1.8 version, but you're suppose to have the 1.7 version if you use the original ubuntu 12.10 repository list.

Comment: Well, I need to have 1.8! Can I, somehow, edit the list or sth.?!

Comment: You can't edit this list, it's the ubuntu official list. 

However, you can add [this ppa](https://launchpad.net/~git-core/+archive/ppa) and always has the latest git release.